# Error ggplot "Computation failed in `stat_bin()`:"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo un dataframe con un conjunto de datos parecido a este:

```
           Muestra_typo           fecha_recolección
              Humana                   2020-02-05
              Humana                   2020-02-06
              Vegetal                  2020-02-06
              Vegetal                  2020-02-06
              Humana                   2020-02-18
              Vegetal                  2020-02-22
              Humana                   2020-02-24
              Vegetal                  2020-02-24
              Humana                   2020-02-24
              Humana                   2020-02-26
              Vegetal                  2020-02-26
              Humana                   2020-02-26
              Humana                   2020-02-06
              Humana                   2020-02-05
              Vegetal                  2020-02-06
```

Me gustaría hacer una representación gráfica de la distribución temporal de cada una de las muestras por tipo de muestra.
Para ello he ejecutado el siguiente script:

```
cdat <- ddply(Datos, "Muestra_typo", summarise, rating.mean=mean(fecha_recolección))
cdat

            ggplot(Datos, aes(x=fecha_recolección, fill=Muestra_typo)) +
              geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="identity") +
              geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=rating.mean,  colour=SexoMuestra_typo
                         linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_bin()`:
The number of histogram bins must be less than 1,000,000.
Did you make `binwidth` too small?
```

¿Por qué no obtengo el gráfico deseado?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola @Adrían duda de que tamaño es la base original ?

Comment: Hola @RUBENlopez el tamaño es de 3200 filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve investigando el porque del error en la pagina donde viene la documentación de ggplot2 la cual se encuentra en el siguiente [enlace](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) , el cual en la parte del tamaño de los bins menciona lo siguiente

> El ancho de los bins en una variable de tipo fecha es igual al numero de días en cada fecha

Realice una prueba con los datos que nos compartes y si eliminas el parámetro de "binwidth" funciona correctamente (hasta la parte del histograma, ya que no cuento con los datos que forman la grafica de violín), supongo que al ser una fecha  en automático selecciona el tipo el tamaño del bin

te muestro el resultado que obtengo eliminando este parametro

```
Datos<-readxl::read_excel("C:/Users/rall8/Desktop/Stack/df_histo.xlsx")
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(Datos, aes(x=fecha_recolección, fill=Muestra_typo)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=1, position="identity")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Rubén, tienes razón que al eliminar esa característica obtengo el histrograma. Muchas gracias